# CSS :read-only is applied to elements that are not readonly

Tags: html, css

can someone explain to me why the css pseudo class `:read-only` is applied to elements that are not readonly?

See https://codepen.io/xsrf/pen/RwgZepb

I tested this in recent Edge, Chrome and Firefox. All apply the `input:read-only` to `<input type="button" />`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_read-only.asp says

> The :read-only selector selects elements which are "readonly". Form elements with a "readonly" attribute are defined as "readonly".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly says:

> When an input has the readonly attribute, the :read-only pseudo-class also applies to it. Conversely, inputs that support the readonly attribute but don't have the attribute set match the :read-write pseudo-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#ref-for-read-only-pseudo) says:

> An element matches `:read-write` if it is user-alterable, as defined by the document language. Otherwise, it is `:read-only`.

Buttons are not user-alterable, thus `:read-only`.

Comment: Thx, makes sense. Guess I have to tell a huge software company that they goofed up then. All the controls in the software are greyed out because input:read-only is applied to all controls 

Comment: @xsrf Just sent a chat to my dev team, because I could swear that I saw some wrongly grayed out buttons in our application yesterday too :D

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem with an input with the type="checkbox". The read-only selector even took the ones without the "readonly" attribute.

While this selected also the inputs not set readonly

```
element:read-only{
   #code
}
```

This chose the elements as I wanted them to.

```
input[readonly]{
   #code
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks for this answer, this is what i was looking for.